# Is there a name given to matrices of the form A'XA or AXA'? A is either symmetric or NOT.

Tags: symmetric-groups, symmetry, symmetric-matrices

I understand that $x'Ax$ is generally called the quadratic form, with $x$ being a vector and $A$ is symmetric.

Is there a name given to matrices of the form $AXA$?
$A$ is symmetric, and $X$ here is a matrix which may not be symmetric.

**Edit:**
*Case 2:* 
If $A$ is not symmetric and *not an identity*, is there a name given to any of the forms $A'XA$ or $AXA'$?

Comment: All (square) matrices have this form: For any $X$, $X = I X I$.

Comment: Every matrix can be written in that form by picking the identity for $A$